# .value from where it is coming?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT ( SELECT 'White' AS Color1,
 'Blue' AS Color2,
 'Black' AS Color3,
 'Light' AS 'Color4/@Special',
 'Green' AS Color4,
 'Red' AS Color5
 FOR
 XML PATH('COLOR'),
 TYPE
 ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
```

from where is that `.value` method coming? I mean is it part of select statement or string methods or built-in TSQL function?

Comment: is that your full query?

Comment: Not full query. But trying to understand more about "value" function. Any pointer to documentation is helpful.

Comment: @bluefeet: It apparently works: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/2985

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`value` is a method used on XML types.  You can read up on it here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx

In your case the `.` is the xPath referencing the current node, and you are treating that data as the SQL Type `NVARCHAR(MAX)`